# tm package in R hangs with small dataset

Tags: r, tm

I have a data.frame of 30k records (company name and other attributes). `dba_nm` is the company name field with longest element < 60 characters.

The R session's memory usage goes up from 100MB to 3GB and hangs when I try the code in `?tm::VectorSource`:

```
ds <- VectorSource(dat$dba_nm)
inspect(Corpus(ds))
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your data so we can try to replicate your problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to print all 30k records to screen? Do something sensible like `inspect(head(Corpus(ds)))` instead.

Comment: I've found that the `tm` package doesn't like factors, so my guess is that your `dat` object contains factors instead of character vectors.

Comment: @Joshua:Now that was a useful answer....

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was getting a dataframe (dat) off a database and trying to read one of the columns (dba_nm) into a vectorsource. It turns out you have to convert it into a character vector.
the following code works:

```
> cs <- as.character(dat$dba_nm)
> ds <- VectorSource(cs)
> Corpus(ds)
A corpus with 30453 text documents
```